# How To Set The Order of Items HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

When I get to anything below 760px, the order is messed up. I'm using flexbox, I have it so if it is above 760px then they are side by side. If they are below 760px, then they are stacked. Once they are stacked, that's where I have an error.

ABOVE 760px: [image]
BELOW 760px: [image]

Above 760px is correct, and for below 760px, the image should be above the text.

I know you have to use order, but for some reason, it isn't changing on my end.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 760px)
{
    
    /*section :nth-child(1) {
        order: 2;
    }
    */
}
```

```html
 <div>
        <h1>Museum of the Arts</h1>
        
        <figure>
            <img src="images/sunday.jpg" alt="sunday">
            <figcaption>Sunday Afternoon on the Island of La Grande Jatte</figcaption>
        </figure>
         
        <section>
            <p><span>Sunday Afternoon on the Island of La Grande Jatte</span>, painted in 1884, is one of Georges Seurat's most famous works. It is a leading example of pointillist technique, executed on a large canvas. Seurat's composition includes a number of Parisians at a park on the banks of the River Seine.
         </section>
        
         <section>
             <p><span>Nighthawks</span> is a 1942 oil on canvas painting by Edward Hopper that portrays people in a downtown diner late at night. It has been described as Hopper's best known work and one of the most recognizable paintings in American art Within months of its completion, it was sold to the Art Institute of Chicago on May 13, 1942 for $3,000.</p>
         </section>

        <figure>
            <img src="images/nighthawk.jpg" alt="Nigthawk">
            <figcaption>Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
         
   </div>
```

Comment: `order` work only with a Flexbox or CSS grid layout and you need to remove the space in your selector. Also `section` is not the first child, so your selector will select nothing

Comment: I'm using flexbox, I have it so if it is above 760px then they are side by side. If they are below 760px, then they are stacked. Once they are stacked, that's where I have an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the media query add: `flex-direction: row-reverse;`

Comment: Wouldn't that then place the last image first, and the first image last leading me to the same issue.

Comment: It'll work in your example with one text and one image

Comment: And if you have pairs of image/text, you could group them in containers and apply the direction change to those containers.

Comment: It works but I get the same layout as above 760px. Need them stacked.    flex-flow: column wrap;
        justify-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        /*flex-direction: row-reverse;*/

Comment: please provide a simple version of your work here in a code snippet or codepen or so.. I'll look into it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these

.your_class {
  flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;}
And to know more about flexbox read this
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Keep doing new happy